# conda update scikit-image fails

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, scikit-image

I tried to update my version scikit-image (from 0.11.2 to 0.12.3) and it fails with the following error-message:

```
$ conda update scikit-image
Fetching package metadata .........
Solving package specifications: .

Package plan for installation in environment /Users/.../anaconda:

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    cycler:             0.10.0-py27_0              
    mkl:                2017.0.1-0                 
    singledispatch:     3.4.0.3-py27_0             

The following packages will be UPDATED:

    astropy:            1.0.1-np19py27_0  <unknown> --> 1.3-np111py27_0   
    bcolz:              0.8.1-np19py27_0  <unknown> --> 1.0.0-py27_0      
    blaze-core:         0.7.3-np19py27_0  <unknown> --> 0.9.0-py27_0      
    datashape:          0.4.4-np19py27_1  <unknown> --> 0.5.4-py27_0      
    dynd-python:        0.6.5-np19py27_0  <unknown> --> 0.7.2-py27_0      
    freetype:           2.5.2-0           <unknown> --> 2.5.2-2           
    h5py:               2.4.0-np19py27_0  <unknown> --> 2.6.0-np111py27_2 
    hdf5:               1.8.14-0          <unknown> --> 1.8.17-1          
    libpng:             1.5.13-1          <unknown> --> 1.6.17-0          
    llvmlite:           0.2.2-py27_1      <unknown> --> 0.16.0-py27_0     
    matplotlib:         1.4.3-np19py27_1  <unknown> --> 1.5.1-np111py27_0 
    nltk:               3.0.2-np19py27_0  <unknown> --> 3.2.2-py27_0      
    numba:              0.17.0-np19py27_0 <unknown> --> 0.31.0-np111py27_0
    numexpr:            2.3.1-np19py27_0  <unknown> --> 2.6.2-np111py27_0 
    numpy:              1.9.2-py27_0      <unknown> --> 1.11.3-py27_0     
    odo:                0.3.1-np19py27_0  <unknown> --> 0.4.2-py27_0      
    pandas:             0.15.2-np19py27_1 <unknown> --> 0.19.2-np111py27_1
    patsy:              0.3.0-np19py27_0  <unknown> --> 0.4.1-py27_0      
    pytables:           3.1.1-np19py27_2  <unknown> --> 3.3.0-np111py27_0 
    scikit-image:       0.11.2-np19py27_0 <unknown> --> 0.12.3-np111py27_1
    scikit-learn:       0.15.2-np19py27_0 <unknown> --> 0.18.1-np111py27_1
    scipy:              0.15.1-np19py27_0 <unknown> --> 0.19.0-np111py27_0
    statsmodels:        0.6.1-np19py27_0  <unknown> --> 0.8.0-np111py27_0 

The following packages will be SUPERCEDED by a higher-priority channel:

    abstract-rendering: 0.5.1-np19py27_0  <unknown> --> 0.5.1-np111py27_0 
    blz:                0.6.2-np19py27_0  <unknown> --> removed-0         

Proceed ([y]/n)? y

ERROR conda.core.link:_execute_actions(335): An error occurred while installing package 'defaults::scipy-0.19.0-np111py27_0'.
OSError(17, 'File exists')
Attempting to roll back.



OSError(17, 'File exists')
```

Here are some version details:

```
conda 4.3.14
Python 2.7.12 :: Anaconda custom (x86_64)
MacOS 10.10.5
```

Does anybody have an idea why it fails and how to resolve the problem?

Comment: Can you try uninstalling scipy then repeating the update?

Comment: unfortunately, that does not work. I still get the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might have been a better solution but I could fix it by uninstalling Anaconda and getting a fresh installation